# Mix forms in twig Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I use TWIG and Symfony2. Now i want to mix forms (i need multiple forms).

The Entity Structure is: main-meal(name, date, ...), dessert(name, date, ...).

The html structure should look like this:

> -> day1: form1.food1, form2.food1
>
> -> day2: form1.food2, form2.food2
>
> -> day3: form1.food3, form2.food3
>
> ...

form1 is the main meal
form2 is the dessert

Any idea how i could do this?
Here my code for ONE meal (withoud dessert - would be form2).

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>Neuen Essensplan eintragen</h1>
    {{ form_start(form1, {attr: {class: 'form-inline'}}) }}
        Montag:
        {{ form_widget(form1.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'}, 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Hauptgericht'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form1.zusatzstoff, { 'attr': {'class': 'hide'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form1.datum.day, { 'attr': {'class': 'hdide'}, 'value':  datum[0].day  }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form1.datum.month, { 'attr': {'class': 'hdide'}, 'value':  monat  }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form1.datum.year, { 'attr': {'class': 'hdide'}, 'value':  jahr  }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form1.submit, { 'attr': {'class': 'hide'} }) }}

    {{ form_end(form1) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you can use multiple forms.. right underneight do form_start(form2)... etc

Comment: if you want to use multiple forms on a single page you have to pay attention they have different names e.g: $formFactory->createNamedBuilder(...);

Comment: i want to use form2 in the area of form1, not underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple forms. For what you are trying to do, look specifically into the ["collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) as it will do what you want it to do.